# Batch file to add character

Tags: batch-file

if I have a .txt that has the following:

2005050 "2/19/2005"
2005060 "3/1/2005"
2005070 "3/11/2005"
2005080 "3/21/2005"
2005090 "3/31/2005"

Is there a way for the batch file to read and always add .png in the end of a character of 7.

For example.

2005050.png  "2/19/2005"
2005060.png  "3/1/2005"
2005070.png  "3/11/2005"
2005080.png  "3/21/2005"
2005090.png "3/31/2005"

Comment: Do you want the batch file to update the text file, or create a new text file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This batch file will split each line at the first space, and append .png to the string before the split.  The script reads lines from infile.txt and outputs to outfile.txt.

```
@echo off
echo. > outfile.txt
for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in (infile.txt) do echo %%i.png %%j >> outfile.txt
```

**Update**

Or to delete the outfile.txt first....

```
@echo off
del /q /f outfile.txt
for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in (infile.txt) do echo %%i.png %%j >> outfile.txt
```

**Another Update**

To just add new records to outfile.txt do something like....

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1*" %%i in (infile.txt) do (
    find "%%i.png %%j" outfile.txt > nul
    if errorlevel 1 then (
        echo %%i.png %%j >> outfile.txt
    )
)
```

Comment: echo. > outfile.txt is not needed. It creates a first empty line in outfile.txt

Comment: I put it in to make sure that outfile.txt was blank before the for loop started appending to it.  I could probably just use del to make sure it's not there instead.

Comment: That's what I get for walking away from the computer for a few minutes :)  Good answer

Comment: just reran the batch and it repeats the name over and over . Is there a way to only have those new lines to show up once and not keep repeating. 
I get this:
2005050.png "2/19/2005"
2005060.png "3/1/2005"
2005070.png "3/11/2005"
2005080.png "3/21/2005"
2005090.png "3/31/2005"
2005050.png "2/19/2005"
2005060.png "3/1/2005"
2005070.png "3/11/2005"
2005080.png "3/21/2005"
2005090.png "3/31/2005"
2005050.png "2/19/2005"
2005060.png "3/1/2005"
2005070.png "3/11/2005"
just want to have those line there only once rather than multiple times.

Comment: The problem is the for loop appends to the output file.  To avoid repeating the records you need to delete the output file or blank it out first.

Comment: the problem is that I will  need to keep updating the list with new txt from the original. So right now If I added let say 2005091.png "4/1/2005" to the original list and ran that batch file. I  would get the duplicate names going down the line and the new one. Where I need is only the of them.

Comment: The simplest way to do it is just to recreate outfile.txt completely each time you update the source file.  Will this not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

[Sed for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

```
sed -r "s/^(.......)(.*)/\1.png\2/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

My Answer failed: I did try: but I couldn't get the SET to WORK within the FOR

```
@echo off

set str1=ooo
set str2=ppp

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type testprog.txt') do (

    set str=!%%a!
    echo %%str:~0,7%%.png %%str:~-5,14%% >> tempprog.txt

)

move tempprog.txt testprog.txt
start testprog.txt
```

Maybe someone can edit a working version as I would like to see what
I did wrong...